# GoDaddy API to create subdoman returns "The given domain is not registered, or does not have a zone file"

Tags: godaddy-api

I'm trying to use GoDaddy's API to create a subdomain using the following http request:

```
PATCH /v1/domains/domainName.com/records
Host: api.ote-godaddy.com
Authorization: sso-key API_KEY:API_SECRET
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 100

[
  {
    "data": "111.111.111.111",
    "name": "subdomainName",
    "ttl": 6000,
    "type": "A"
  }
]
```

but I get the following response:

```
{
    "code": "UNKNOWN_DOMAIN",
    "message": "The given domain is not registered, or does not have a zone file"
}
```

Comment: No familiarity with the API, but try specifying the FQDN instead of _just_ the subdomain. How else would they know what it should be created as a subdomain of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please changes the host name as https://api.godaddy.com. your request will be work only production URL.

Please generate Production level API Key & SECRET.

Body: (Raw - Json Type)

[
{
"data": "YourServerIp",
"name": "subdomainName",
"port": 80,
"priority": 10,
"protocol": "string",
"service": "string",
"ttl": 600,
"type": "A"
}
]

Note:

It's only happened when primary domain already exists on your go daddy account

Answer (score 0):

I figured out these requests only work using the production authorization against the production url but won't work using ote-authorization against the ote url. Maybe the url has to be set as an ote domain and not a production domain. Not sure.